# Renaming files by removing compiler stamp

Tags: shell-script, rename, filenames

Given

1. list of directories, e.g. `dirs="Larry Curly Moe"`
2. compiler vendor, e.g. -gcc-M.N.0

the goal is to sweep through each directory and truncate all file names like so:

```
intel-mkl/2018.1.163-gcc-7.1.0             -> intel-mkl/2018.1.163
exuberant-ctags/5.8-gcc-7.1.0              -> exuberant-ctags/5.8
superlu-dist/5.2.2-gcc-7.2.0-openmpi@3.0.0 -> superlu-dist/5.2.2
```

What are efficient and robust strategies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

Start with your sample set of files:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*-gcc-*'
./intel-mkl/2018.1.163-gcc-7.1.0
./superlu-dist/5.2.2-gcc-7.2.0-openmpi@3.0.0
./exuberant-ctags/5.8-gcc-7.1.0
```

Here's a script to trim -gcc-* off the end of any filename:

```
$ cat ex.sh
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(find . -type f -name '*-gcc-*'); do
    mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | sed -e 's/-gcc-.*$//')"
done
```

Run the script:

```
$ bash ex.sh
```

Note that the files no longer contain the -gcc-* suffix:

```
$ find . -type f
./intel-mkl/2018.1.163
./superlu-dist/5.2.2
./exuberant-ctags/5.8
```

Answer (score 1):

**`find`** + **`bash`** solution:

```
find . -type f -name "*-gcc-[0-9]*" -exec bash -c 'fn=${1%-gcc-*}; mv "$1" "$fn"' _ {} \;
```